# Core Data Необходимо работать с одной записью

Tags: swift, coredata

У меня есть сущность - пользователь у него 10 полей мне необходимо работать с этой одной записью (с одной строкой).
Подскажите как поправить класс для работы с этой одной записью (всегда одной строкой).

Класс:
    class DB: NSObject {

```
    var setting: [NSManagedObject] = []
    var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    var appDelegate: AppDelegate


    override init() {
        self.appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)!
        self.managedContext = self.appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        super.init()
    }

    static var instance = DB()

    func userSaveValue(key: String, value: String) {
        // Описание сущности
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: self.managedContext)
        // Создание нового объекта
        let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: self.managedContext)
        // Установка значения атрибута
        managedObject.setValue(value, forKey: key)
        // Извлечение значения атрибута
        let name = managedObject.value(forKey: key)
        print("status = \(name)")
        // Запись объекта
        self.saveContext()
}

func userGetValue(key: String) -> String {
    // Описание сущности
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: self.managedObjectContext)
    // Создание нового объекта
    let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: self.managedObjectContext)
    // Извлечение значения атрибута
    let name = managedObject.value(forKey: key) as! String
    print("name = \(name)")
    return name
}

func saveContext () {
        if managedContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Добавлено:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

        lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
            let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "QalaData")
            container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
                if let error = error {
                    fatalError("Unable to load persistent stores: \(error)")
                }
            }
            return container
        }()
```

Но почему-то записи все добавляются и добавляются а не обновляются.
И прочитать их не получается т.к. их уже много.

Comment: Для начала вам стоит исправить строку: forEntityName: "Гыук"

Comment: Это я описался после копирования.

Answer (score 0):

Как искать, вдруг кому нужно:

```
func search() {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "User")
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %d", 1)
        //request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", 1) //если id - строка

        do {
            var result = try managedContext.fetch(request) as? [User]
            let pin = result?.first?.поле - лидо читаем либо устанавливаем новое значение и сохраняем
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```